# How to check if current time is night

Tags: android

Is there Any service to check if the current time is night considering the winter and summer time changes ?
For example, the night in summer starts after 19:45 (in my local time), but in winter, night starts after 16:45.

My trial was:

```
Boolean isNight;
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
isNight = hour < 6 || hour > 18;
```

This code works only if if the night starts after 18:00, but night time changes according to the time in year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this **[`sunrisesunset-lib`](https://github.com/mikereedell/sunrisesunsetlib-java)** and with a method like this and 
your location you are able to find out it's night or not :

```
private boolean isNight(Location location) {
    SunriseSunsetCalculator calculator = new SunriseSunsetCalculator(location, TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+3:30"));
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar officialSunrise = calculator.getOfficialSunriseCalendarForDate(now);
    Calendar officialSunset = calculator.getOfficialSunsetCalendarForDate(now);
    return !(now.after(officialSunrise) && now.before(officialSunset));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one more code is working for me

```
String time1 = "01:00:00";  
String time2 = "15:00:00";  
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(time2);  
if ((time.isAfter(LocalTime.of(20,11,13))) || (time.isBefore(LocalTime.of(14,49,0))))  
{  
    System.out.println("true");  
}  
else  
{  
    System.out.println("false");  
}
```